# Flutter: How to capture full frame image from camera?

Tags: image, flutter, camera, size

I need to capture the full-frame images (with 4x3 aspect ratio) from the camera in my Flutter app.
The only image I'm getting, however, is 16x9 (which is a little bit cropped).
Also, I cannot find any mention about that in documentation and example.
So, how to get wide, full-frame 4x3 images from camera in my Flutter app?
In my main project I'm using [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) plugin version 0.8.1.

### Steps to Reproduce

Steps can be reproduced with flutter camera example.

1. Download camera library example (https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/camera/camera/example).
2. Set ResolutionPreset.max for CameraController (instead of ResolutionPreset.medium).
3. Take a picture from the back camera.
4. Check its width and height.

**Expected results:**

Full-frame picture with the size  3024x4032, which is 3x4.

**Actual results:**

Picture size is 2160 × 3840, which is 9x16.

The same behavior can be reproduced on all devices, both iOS, and Android.
I checked it on Pixel 3a and iPhone XS.

```
flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.2, on macOS 11.1 20C69 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 2.0.2 at /Users/yurii.dvornyk/Documents/flutter
    • Framework revision 8962f6dc68 (6 weeks ago), 2021-03-11 13:22:20 -0800
    • Engine revision 5d8bf811b3
    • Dart version 2.12.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/yurii.dvornyk/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/yurii.dvornyk/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.55.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.21.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 90.0.4430.85
```

Answer (score 1):

if you see sources of camera plugin for iOS: `CameraPlugin.m` on line 280 you can see that resolutions are writed manually and for Android: `CameraUtils.java` on line 80 same thing.

iOs documentation about resolutions: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturesession/preset

Android documentation about resolutions: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/CamcorderProfile

| iPhone 5S | iPod Touch | iPhone6/6S/SE/7/8/X |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1920x1080 (HD) | Y | Y |
| 2560x1440 (UHD) | N | Y |
| 3840x2160 (4K) | N | Y |
| 3840x1440 | N | Y |
| 4096x2048 | N | N |
| 3200x4800 | N | N |
| 2280x5760 | N | N |